Unable to receive confirmation after sending an email using Microsoft Graph API
I have a server that sends an email using "microsoft-graph-client" library. The email is sent successfully, but it seems that there is no response coming from the Graph API afterwards, only a readable stream.
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }

This is how I call the API:
async function send(client, mailData){
  await client.api('/users/sender.email@example.com/sendMail')
    .post(mailData).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
}

I also tried to split the process into two awaits, but in that case the latter one is never completed, never logging the response.
async function send(client, mailData){
  let clientData = await client.api('/users/sender.email@example.com/sendMail')
  let response = await clientData.post(mailData)
  console.log(response)
}

I'm using
const { Client } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
const { TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider } = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials');
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require('@azure/identity');

to poll the API
And this is how I configure the client
async function getMailer(mailuser) {
   const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    mailuser.auth.tenant,    // Directory (tenant) ID
    mailuser.auth.user,    // Application (client) ID
    mailuser.auth.pass     // Application Secret
   );
   const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, {
    scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
   });

   const client = Client.initWithMiddleware({
    debugLogging: true,
    authProvider
   });
   return client;
}

Is there some way to either get or access the response from the Graph API, or should I try to skip using the library and send the request directly using axios?

Perhaps you can try switching to JSON mode in the response as per the docs?
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/OtherAPIs.md#responsetype
Example: .responseType(MicrosoftGraph.ResponseType.JSON)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream explains how to work with a ReadableStream.
